# Correct validation of allennlp auto-encoder

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoder, allennlp

I'm trying to implement a model similar to https://aclanthology.org/N19-1289.pdf using `allennlp`

This consists of two parallel input modules, an embedding module that embeds the inputs and a parallel module that encodes the labels. MSE loss is used to encourage both to produce the same encoding.

Then the output from the label embedded is passed through an output module which recreates the original labels. I have this working, however, I believe that I'm not implementing validation correctly. For validation, the output from the input embedded should be passed through the decoder, not the output from the label encoder.

I'm not sure how to implement this in `allennlp` though, I need to detect if the model is being trained or validated in the forward method despite both receiving the same arguments (i.e. both x and y are provided).

My current code is

```
    embedded = self._embedder(text)
    if labels is not None:
        encoded = self._encoder(labels)
        decoded = self._decoder(encoded)

        # compute loss / accuracy
        encoder_loss = MSE(embedded, encoded)
        reconstruction_loss = CDL(labels, decoded)
    else:
        decoded = self._decoder(embedded)
```

But what I want to do is

```
    embedded = self._embedder(text)
    if labels is not None:
        encoded = self._encoder(labels)
        if training:
            decoded = self._decoder(encoded)
        else:
            decoded = self._decoder(embedded)

        # compute loss / accuracy
        encoder_loss = MSE(embedded, encoded)
        reconstruction_loss = CDL(labels, decoded)
    else:
        decoded = self._decoder(embedded)
```

How do I do this? How do I ensure that when the model is validated, but labels are supplied that the model doesn't pass the validation labels to the encoder (i.e. if this happens the validation isn't testing how well the embedded replicates the encoder)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, there's a `module.training` property which is set when model.eval() is called.